# undefined img src found by class

Tags: javascript, image, src

So the html code of the img src that I am trying to define a variable from and just put it in an alert for starters looks like this:

```
<img class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image" data-load="false" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg" data-image-dimensions="750x1124" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-position-mode="standard" data-parent-ratio="0.7" alt="White" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg?format=500w" style="font-size: 0px; left: -0.312278px; top: 0px; width: 327.625px; height: 491px; position: relative;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1530976058504_955" data-image-resolution="500w">
```

I am trying to get the img src with the following

```
 var picture = document.getElementsByClassName("ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image loaded").src;
 alert(picture);
```

It returns

```
Undefined
```

I will mention the img src is deep within multiple divs whose ID is random.

Comment: Why are you using both class? Just use any one to select

Comment: still undefined

Comment: If there is more images with same class then it will return an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, try the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image loaded")[0].src;
```

Working example :

```js
var picture = document.getElementsByClassName("ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image loaded")[0].src;
 alert(picture);
```

```html
<img class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image loaded" data-load="false" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg" data-image-dimensions="750x1124" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-position-mode="standard" data-parent-ratio="0.7" alt="White" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg?format=500w" style="font-size: 0px; left: -0.312278px; top: 0px; width: 327.625px; height: 491px; position: relative;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1530976058504_955" data-image-resolution="500w">
```

Comment: why did it come back empty?

Comment: @dixiemotors empty? It is not empty, it returns an array of elements. so to  access a element you have to access it by its index.

Comment: I will but the alert is empty.

Comment: @dixiemotors it will alert the source of img. I made made an example snippet its working fine. Please have a look

Comment: your snippet works but the live example wont https://goldietees.com/signature/short-sleeve-v-neck-tee

Comment: Do one thing remove that hardcoded 0 n console the returned value

Comment: If you don't want an array use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array.
So you need to handle the returned value as you will handle an array.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image loaded")[0].src;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use document.getElementsByClassName('xxx')[0] instead

Comment: **Post when you have a different solution than the existing answers**. This doesn't give any value add.

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return an array of elements, which you need to loop over or get the item by index.

We can skip that process by use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which will return the first found item as a single element instead.

```js
let picture = document.querySelector('.ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image').src
console.log(picture)
```

```html
<img class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item-image" data-load="false" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg" data-image-dimensions="750x1124" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-position-mode="standard" data-parent-ratio="0.7" alt="White" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58068e2f5016e12d2c5502ff/5807a2df8419c2ae30bc4d69/5a3dd5740852297f08f5a12c/1529335692585/White-Goldie-V-neck-Tee.jpg?format=500w" style="font-size: 0px; left: -0.312278px; top: 0px; width: 327.625px; height: 491px; position: relative;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1530976058504_955" data-image-resolution="500w">
```